# How to add 'Open with PowerShell' to context-menu of folder object and load profile when PS starts

Tags: windows, powershell

When I right-click on folder or white-space inside folder, I want to have a menu option that will launch PowerShell in that location, then I want to run a function/alias which will perform the job of flattening the directory and overwrite if file with same name exists.

Update:
Using get-help cmdlet on powershell, I managed to hack this command that flattens the working directory and overwrites if file exists.

```
gci -r -file | move -force -destination $PWD
```

Update:
I added "Open with PowerShell" to context-menu by `regedit`

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Open with PowerShell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Open with PowerShell\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open with PowerShell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open with PowerShell\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"
```

then adding a `function` was similar to many other languages:

```
function flatten { gci -r -file | move -force -destination $PWD }
```

But I can't seem to get this to automatically load when I open powershell. In bash, I would put this in `.bashrc` or `.profile` and it would be loaded.

I added `profile.ps1` file with the `function` in `$pshome`, now I get this error:

```
. : File C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled
on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:3
+ . 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1'
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Not sure if changing security setting is the only way around this.

How do I allow loading script/alias as safe as possible?

Update:

Changing command to entry below in `regedit` loads the function I need:

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'; function flatten { gci -r -file | move -destination $PWD -force }
```

This is a workaround. I'm still interested in knowing how to load a profile without making risky changes to OS security.

Comment: I guess language recommendings are off-topic here (but use powershell).

Comment: @SimonS language recommendation wouldn't be off topic. It would determine the next step.

Comment: So, in the end, what is your question? How to create a command alias? Or perhaps how to add Powershell to the context menu? Please clarify and either remove this question and ask a new one or remove all the other stuff.

Comment: @DanielB I will edit and remove. Question is how to safely load alias/function from profile file with every powershell start. Since there is some useful information, I won't remove everything in regards to my previous question.

Comment: @SimonS any powershell tips?

Comment: @sdkks you can either `Set-Executionpolicy RemoteSigned` to make your OS PowerShell friendly (read `get-help about_Execution_Policies`) or you can add `-executionpolicy bypass` to your powershell.exe call to bypass the execution policy

Comment: @sdkks and right now your only loading the `flattern` function into cache, but you don't use it. I'd actually not put the command into a function but just use it like this `-command Set-Location '%V'; gci -r -file | move -destination $PWD -force ` also you have to make sure if `$PWD` has a value, i don't think it has with your command

Answer (score 0):

See if [this](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx/blob/master/Src/Pscx/Modules/Utility/Pscx.Utility.psm1#L70) implementation of similar functionality helps.